# Derivation of Kruskal to Schwarzchild coordinate transformation

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems

The first step that gets us to Kruskal coordinates is usually to consider Schwartzschild Universe and apply the tortoise coordinate transformation
$$ r^\ast \doteq r + 2M \ln{\left|\frac{r}{2M}-1\right|}$$
(that seems not a diffeomorphism to me because $ \partial r^\ast/\partial r = r/(r-2M) $
and for $r\to 2M$ it explodes; I wonder if it's this to cause troubles in my following derivation).

The question I have is about the relation $(\bar{u},\bar{v})\to(t,r)$, where the former are the Kruskal and the latter the Schwarzschild coordinates. I'll jump straight to the critical passages. Kruskal coordinates may be defined as
$$ \begin{cases} \bar{u} \doteq -4M e^{-\frac{u}{4M}} \\ \bar{v} \doteq 4M e^{\frac{v}{2M}} \end{cases} $$
where $(u,v)$ are the usual lightcone coordinates $u=t-r^\ast,v=t+r^\ast$ and by this very definition really seems to me that $\bar{u}$ will always be negative and $\bar{v}$ positive. After a bit of manipulation we should get to
$$ \begin{cases} e^{\frac{t}{2M}} = - \frac{\bar{v}}{\bar{u}} \\ e^{\frac{r}{2M}} \left|\frac{r}{2M}-1\right| = -\frac{\bar{u}\bar{v}}{(4M)^2} \end{cases} $$
and multiplying the two we have $\bar{v}^2$ equals something: multipling the inverse of the first equation with the second we get $\bar{u}^2$ equals something else. But the signs of $\bar{u},\bar{v}$ seemed fixed to me so
$$ \begin{cases} - 4M e^{\frac{r-t}{4M}} \sqrt{\left| \frac{r}{2M}-1 \right|} = \bar{u} \\ 4M e^{\frac{r+t}{4M}} \sqrt{\left| \frac{r}{2M}-1 \right|} = \bar{v} \end{cases} $$
that is not different for the $r>2M$ and the $r<2M$ cases, as stated for example [here](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_di_Kruskal-Szekeres) *.

What I did wrong in deriving the $(\bar{u},\bar{v})\to(t,r)$ relation?

<sub>* Sorry but the english page derivation is different: this one is instead more similar to the book I'm using "Quantum Effects in Gravity - Mukhanov, Winitzki" and I think the formulas there are clear by themselves. I wans't also able to find an internet page with the full derivation of the Kruskal-Schwarzschild transformation to put as an alternative. If you know a link please put in the comment and I substitute immediately!</sub>

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407108/line-element-in-kruskal-coordinates

Comment: @Eli I really thank you, but I still can't find the answer to my question

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @TimRias I need to derive the relation from Schwarzschild to Kruskal coordiante, or viceversa doesn't matter, and show that it changes form in the cases $r>2M$ and $r<2M$